# java inheritance with incompatible constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I'm having a bunch of classes that I can not change; all these classes have a common ancestor (other than Object) that declares and implements the majority of their properties and methods.

Let's say, we have an inheritance tree like this (for illustration only):

```
class Vehicle
    class Bicycle extends Vehicle
    class Skateboard extends Vehicle
    class Boat extends Vehicle
    class Car extends Vehicle
    class Aircraft extends Vehicle
        class Jetplane extends Aircraft
        class Helicopter extends Aircraft
        ...
    class Truck extends Vehicle
    ...
```

While `class Vehicle` is actually more like an abstract class (it is not really, but it is never instantiated on its own behalf), objects of `class Aircraft` are created occasionally.

Now the point: the objects can have interrelationships that are not reflected by the classes. Since it is quite a bouquet of classes and the collection is subject to change every once in a while, it is not practical to maintain a subclass for each of the classes that implement the missing behavior.

My approach is therefore to have one class that serves as a wrapper for the above classes.
The constructor takes as a parameter the class of the respective object, which is then instantiated using reflection.

```
class VehicleW
{
  // fields
  public  boolean isInitialized=false;
  private Vehicle fVehicle;
  ...

  // constructors
  public VehicleW(Class aClass, ...)
  {
    Class VehicleClass = Vehicle.class;
    if (!VehicleClass.isAssignableFrom(aClass))
      return;

    // <the reflection magic here>
    ...
    // and on success mark this object as usable
    isInitialized=true;
  }
}
```

A constructor without arguments doesn't really make sense here. But now `class Aircraft` and its subclasses want some extra properties, so I thought I could establish a `class AircraftW extends VehicleW` that takes care of them.

The modification then looks like this:

```
  // fields
  private Aircraft fAircraft;

  // constructors
  public AircraftW(Class aClass, ...)
  {
    Class AircraftClass = AirCraft.class;
    if (!AircraftClass.isAssignableFrom(aClass))
      return;

    // <the reflection magic here>
    ...
    // and on success mark this object as usable
    isInitialized=true;
  }
```

But this fails, because Java intelligently inserts a call to the parameterless constructor of the ancestor, which is not present (and doesn't make sense, as already said).

It also doesn't make sense to call the parameterized super(), because I initialize a field of `class Vehicle` then. Okay, I can later in my `AircraftW()` just set that field to `null`, but that doesn't seem right.

Is there a way around this? Or am I taking an absolutely wrong approach? I thought about generics, but I can't seem to find a point using it. Interfaces? I'm not that much of a Java expert, so any recommendations are welcome.

**Edit (not unsolved** (to avoid the term *solved*)**)** Well, below you find a working program. I can't put it down as an answer, because Thomas led me to this code... with his answer... which I accepted as the solution... I can't see what's wrong with that.

Thanks, Thomas, for pointing me in the right direction.

For the sceptical, here the complete source code of a test program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class Vehicle { public Vehicle(){} }
class Bicycle extends Vehicle { public Bicycle(){} }
class Skateboard extends Vehicle { public Skateboard(){} }
class Boat extends Vehicle { public Boat(){} }
class Car extends Vehicle { public Car(){} }
class Aircraft extends Vehicle { public Aircraft(){} }
class Jetplane extends Aircraft { public Jetplane(){} }
class Helicopter extends Aircraft { public Helicopter(){} }
class Truck extends Vehicle { public Truck(){} }

class VehicleW
{
  protected Vehicle fVehicle=null;
  public    boolean isInitialized=false;

  public VehicleW(Class aClass)
  {
    if (checkVehicle(aClass))
      if ((fVehicle=makeVehicle(aClass))!=null)
        isInitialized=true;
  }

  protected boolean checkVehicle(Class aClass)
  {
    Class tClass = Vehicle.class;
    return (tClass.isAssignableFrom(aClass));
  }

  protected Vehicle makeVehicle(Class aClass)
  {
    Vehicle tVehicle = null;

    System.out.format("trying to create %s\n",aClass.toString());

    Constructor c;

    try
    {
      c=aClass.getConstructor();
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
      System.out.format("  no constructor found\n");
      return null;
    }

    try
    {
      tVehicle=(Vehicle)c.newInstance();
    }
    catch(InvocationTargetException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    catch(InstantiationException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return tVehicle;
  }

  public Vehicle getVehicle()
  {
    if (!isInitialized)
      return null;
    return fVehicle;
  }
  public Class getWClass()
  {
    if (!isInitialized)
      return null;
    return fVehicle.getClass();
  }
}

class AircraftW extends VehicleW
{
  public AircraftW(Class aClass)
  {
    super(aClass);
    /*
    Class tClass=Aircraft.class;
    if (!tClass.isAssignableFrom(aClass))
      return;
    isInitialized=true;
    */
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean checkVehicle(Class aClass)
  {
    Class tClass = Aircraft.class;
    return (tClass.isAssignableFrom(aClass));
  }
}

class program
{
  public static void tellme(VehicleW vx)
  {
    String s = "failed";
    if (vx.getVehicle()!=null)
      s="succeeded";
    System.out.format("  making %s for %s %s\n",
                       vx.getWClass(),vx.getClass(),s);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    VehicleW  v1, v2, v3;
    AircraftW a1, a2, a3;

    v1=new VehicleW(Bicycle.class);
    tellme(v1);
    v2=new VehicleW(Boat.class);
    tellme(v2);
    v3=new VehicleW(Helicopter.class);
    tellme(v3);

    a1=new AircraftW(Helicopter.class);
    tellme(a1);
    a2=new AircraftW(Aircraft.class);
    tellme(a2);
    a3=new AircraftW(Truck.class);
    tellme(a3);

    return;
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
trying to create class Bicycle
  making class Bicycle for class VehicleW succeeded
trying to create class Boat
  making class Boat for class VehicleW succeeded
trying to create class Helicopter
  making class Helicopter for class VehicleW succeeded
trying to create class Helicopter
  making class Helicopter for class AircraftW succeeded
trying to create class Aircraft
  making class Aircraft for class AircraftW succeeded
  making null for class AircraftW failed
```

Comment: The problem with this type of question is that without considerably more knowledge of what the system you're building is trying to achieve it's hard to suggest a suitable design (and even then it'll be opinion to some extent).  What I would say, is that if your constructors are 'incompatible' within the inheritance hierarchy, then that should be telling you that inheritance isn't the correct technique to use with the entities you're modeling

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the word *(solved)*.  Add your own answer below, and then mark that answer as accepted so that the system flags the question as green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like the factory pattern so you might want to look into that.

What you basically would do is something like this:

```
class VehicleFactory {
  public static Vehicle createAircraft( /*Aircraft specific parameters*/) {
    //build and return Aircraft, you can call your reflection magic here
  }

  public static Vehicle createBoat( /*Boatspecific parameters*/) {
    //build and return Boat, you can call your reflection magic here 
  }
}
```

Additionally, you might want to look into the builder pattern.

In your approach there are several issues:

- Prematurely returning from a constructor would still kept the created object, it might just not be properly initialized (you're using an attribute to signal full initialization but what do you do with uninitialized objects besides removing them? In that case `initialized` should not be a property of the objects or wrappers themselves).
- If you have such a high number of subclasses you might want to check what the differences are. It might be a more flexible approach to use composition instead of inheritance.

Example of the last point:

```
class Vehicle {
  VehicleType type; //e.g. Aircraft, Boat, Car
  Set<Features> features; //e.g. 2 wheels, 4 wheels, wings etc.
  Behavior behavior; //Class to implement specific behavior, depending on your needs
}

class AircraftBehavior extends Behavior {
  void fly() {
    //implements flying mechanic
  }

  //method overridden/implemented from Behavior
  @Override
  void move() {  
    fly();
  }
}

//create an aircraft
Vehicle aircraft = new Vehicle( VehicleType.AIRCRAFT, new HashSet<Feature>(new WingsFeature()), new AircraftBehavior());
```

The last part would also be predestined for using the factor or builder pattern.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with those objects other than dropping them. But seeing that an object could just not be created in this way is, imho, better than involving exceptions and corresponding handlers (or just see the whole application die). --- I will look for the factory pattern.

Comment: About that composition example: Unluckily I don't have any influence on `class Vehicle` and its descendants... If I had, I wouldn't find a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

When child class can not full fill the contract of constructor with parent class. Then at same place exists a design defect.

The issue/reason can be that the child class is not valid as a child class or the parent class has to many functionalities.

For your example is really hard to tell what is breaking the contract. But the best and most flexible thing to work with are interfaces.

You claim that you are not an expert in Java. Interfaces are just a concept in Object Oriented programming in case you look for any carrier in this area you should be familiar with them. SO this might the time for you to learn more about interfaces and software design.

Comment: The optimal solution would be to modify the collection of classes, but that is unfortunately impossible. I thought about Interfaces, too, but I don't see how they could help here. The problem is only with creation of the wrapped object. When I implement `class AircraftW`'s constructor to also allow for `Vehicle.class` to be passed, the rest is fine. But that way I don't have a consistency check.